# Tokenizer and print it

Tags: python, printing, tokenize

After tokenizer my list of strings im trying to get the value of the words and its number's associate. f.e:  the = 3 
how can I do it??  (python)
here is the code

```
sentences_train, sentences_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences_train)

X_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences_train)
X_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences_test)

vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(['the'])